# Open jQuery Dialog from dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I add content to my page dynamically (adding rows to a table).

I want that a modal dialog with content from a foreign URL will be opened by clicking on the table row.

That is what I have. The dialog will open, but without content...

```
newRow.onclick = function() {
    $(".detail_popup").dialog({
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui)
        {
            $(this).load("http://www.google.com");
        },
        //autoOpen: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 600,
        title: "Detailed Info",
        resizable: false,
    });
};
```

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your problem is not that your click event is failing (as the answers above have addressed) but simply the fact that nothing loads into the dialog that is displayed?

I just tried your code example and I think it's a security issue with jQuery not wanting to load the www.google.com, since it's from a different domain. It works fine when I use a url that points to some content from the same domain. Did you try that yet?

Answer (score 0):

If the element that's triggering the action has been dynamically added to the DOM, you'll need to use the "live" event of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/live/

For instance:

```
$("newRowSelector").live("click", function(){

    $(".detail_popup").dialog({
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui)
        {
            $(this).load("http://www.google.com");
        },
        //autoOpen: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 600,
        title: "Detailed Info",
        resizable: false,
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a newly added element then you need to delegate the event to the parent element so that the click event shall be attached to the newly added row,,

```
$('table').on('tr' , 'click', function() {
    $(".detail_popup").dialog({
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui)
        {
            $(this).load("http://www.google.com");
        },
        //autoOpen: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 600,
        title: "Detailed Info",
        resizable: false,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="add-row" value="Add row" /><br />

<table id="my-table">
    <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
</table>

<div id="detail-popup">
    <iframe>temp</iframe>
</div>​
```

jQuery:

```
$('#detail-popup').dialog({
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui)
    {
        $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.microsoft.com');
    },
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 500,
    height: 600,
    title: "Detailed Info",
    resizable: false
});

$('#add-row').click(function() {
   $('#my-table').append('<tr><td>New Row</td></tr>');
});

$('#my-table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $('#detail-popup').dialog('open');
});​
```

Few notes:

1. You'll want to use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as `.live` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.
2. You'll need to load an external site into an `iframe`, or load it server side, then into your modal dialog div.
3. The Google homepage has some scripts to not allow you to load www.google.com into an `iframe`.  I know people talk about it on SO a lot, but I'm not sure if there is a workaround.  As a result, I'm loading www.microsoft.com in my example.
4. I added an id to the `table`, just to make things more explicit when using the `.on` function.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/YEs9R/1/